# Decode json string PHP

Tags: php, json

I would like to get the values for 'datelog_collected' and 'value' fields:

> {
>     "data": [
>       {
>         "datelog_collected": "2016-09-01 13:57:13",
>         "value": "36.06"
>       }
>     ]
>   }

So far, i tried with json_decode but without success. I want this to stay as an object. Thanks

Comment: What exactly did you try? `json_decode` should have no problem with this.

Comment: What does _"with no success"_ mean?

Comment: It means i can't access the values when i try something like $object->property...

Answer (score 1):

If you use

```
$object = json_decode($your_JSON_string);
```

`datelog_collected` and `value` will *not* be properties of the resulting `$object`.

The object will have only one property, `data`. `data` is a numerically indexed array (that is what the square brackets in the JSON mean) which contains one object. The properties you want belong to *that* object.

So you can get what you want with `$object->data[0]->datelog_collected`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you use json_decode as:

```
$res=json_decode('{ "data": [ { "datelog_collected": "2016-09-01 13:57:13", "value": "36.06" } ] }');
```

$res would be an object so you can access: `$res->data`

And if you add second parameter `true` (json as array)

```
$res=json_decode('{ "data": [ { "datelog_collected": "2016-09-01 13:57:13", "value": "36.06" } ] }', true);
```

$res would be an array so you can access: `$res["data"]`

Comment: I agree with your solution but how do i get the value of "value" for instance? $res->data->value?

Comment: `$res`is an object but `$res->data`is an array with an object inside it. Hence you'll have to use `$res->data[0]->datelog_collected` to get the value store in `datelog_collected`

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
<?php
$datelog_collected=array();
$datelog_value=array();
$data='{ "data": [ { "datelog_collected": "2016-09-01 13:57:13", "value": "36.06" } ] }';
$data_array=json_decode($data,true);//true create array if you want object then remove true
if(is_array($data_array)&&!empty($data_array))
{
    foreach ($data_array as $key => $value) {
    if(is_array($value))
    {       
        foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
            foreach ($value1 as $key2 => $value2) {
            if($key2=="datelog_collected")
            {
                $datelog_collected[]=$value2;
            }else{
                $datelog_value[]=$value2;
            }
            }
        }
    }
    }

    //here is datelog_collected
    var_dump($datelog_collected);
    echo "<br/>-----------------------<br/>";
        //here is datelog_value
    var_dump($datelog_value);

}

?>
```

> check working link http://main.xfiddle.com/7ffb488b/json_decoder.php

Comment: Just posting a bunch of overly complicated code without any explanation doesn't really help any one..